# Perl 5 - longest token matching in regexp (using alternation)

Tags: regex, perl

Is possible to force a Perl 5 regexp match longest possible string, if the regexp is, for example:

```
a|aa|aaa
```

I found is probably default in perl 6, but in perl 5, how i can get this behavior?

EXAMPLE pattern:

`[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`

If I have string `2.10.2014`, then first match will be 2, which is ok; but the next match will be 1, and this is not ok because it should be 10. Then 2014 will be 4 subsequently matches 2,0,1,4, but it should be 2014 using [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]. I know I could use [0-9]+, but I can't.

Comment: How about listing the alternatives in the reverse order, longest first.  I thought that Perl regexes were greedy, but it appears not when it comes to alternation like that.

Comment: jonathan leffler: i can't, it is condition it must retrieve longest possible string, but i am not who will write those patterns. If this isn't possible , than i must write some algorithm for generating xy patterns from one with alternatives and then compare length of matches.

Comment: The longest possible match without using `+` or `*` means there is some finite number of states that are matched against.  If the canidate string is longer than the number of states it will not match the longest possible number of states.  Why can't you use `\d+`?  What is the problem behind the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Borodin If you have a RE of `\d\d\d\d` and a string of `12345.67` it will not match the longest possible run of of digits.  For any RE where there is a finite number of `\d` and not using one of the looping constructs (this is known as a [Star free language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-free_language)) if you have a string that is longer than the number of states in the aperiodic finite state automaton which the RE represents, you will not match the longest possible string. There is a problem that is trying to be solved - but we are getting the tech side of it, but not the real question.

Comment: @MichaelT i mean longest possible using that pattern, not longest possible ever on the world.

Comment: @MichaelT: I presume you are trying to impress, as formal language theory is unlikely to help the OP. And you don't express yourself well, as `\d\d\d\d` most definitely *will* match the longest possible run of digits in `1234.67`.

Comment: @Krab: you should describe your *actual problem*. What are you trying to do and what data are you given? It seems we aren't helping you but it is impossible to tell what you want to know.

Answer (score 4):

General solution: Put the longest one first.

```
my ($longest) = /(aaa|aa|a)/
```

Specific solution: Use

```
my ($longest) = /([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{1,2})/
```

If you can't edit the pattern, you'll have to find every possibility and find the longest of them.

```
my $longest;
while (/([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])/g) {
   $longest = $1 if length($1) > length($longest);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The alternation will use the *first* alternative that matches, so just write `/aaa|aa|a/` instead.

For the example you have shown in your question, just put the longest alternative first like I said:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]
```

Comment: I can't ensure it, but i need longest possible string. It can't be done in perl 5 regexp by using some features?

Comment: Please modify your question to explain what you mean.

Comment: I mean how i can get longest possible string, so if i have [0-9]|[0-9][0-9], then 22 gives me 2 and then 2, so it is 2 matches, but i need one match 22. Don't ask me why, it is for school. I know i can generate all possible patterns and then check, which is longest, but ....

Comment: @Krab What you have written does not make sense. Please edit your question to give several sample inputs along with what you **want** it to match using a particular pattern.  Try using the digit example, but make it clear; I cannot understand it as written, because I do not see any alternation there.

Answer (score 2):

The sanest solution I can see for unknown patterns is to match every possible pattern, look at the length of the matched substrings and select the longest substring:

```
my @patterns = (qr/a/, qr/a(a)/, qr/b/, qr/aaa/);
my $string = "aaa";

my @substrings = map {$string =~ /($_)/; $1 // ()} @patterns;

say "Matched these substrings:";
say for @substrings;

my $longest_token = (sort { length $b <=> length $a } @substrings)[0];

say "Longest token was: $longest_token";
```

Output:

```
Matched these substrings:
a
aa
aaa
Longest token was: aaa
```

For known patterns, one would sort them manually so that first-match is the same as longest-match:

```
"aaa" =~ /(aaa|aa|b|a)/;
say "I know that this was the longest substring: $1";
```

Comment: Yes i know i can do that, but it can be maybe difficult in long pattern with many nested alternatives and escape chars etc. so i want avoid it, but seems it isn't possible in perl5.

Comment: @Krab There is no problem with escape chars (I used `qr//`, the regex quote). You can longest-match any regex, no matter how complex. You cannot easily longest-match multiple alternations (eg. `/(a||aa)(b||bb)/` where `||` is a hypothetical longest-match operator). Ikegami shows a slightly more general approach in his last code example, which might be extendable. But no, there is no built-in support in Perl5 regexes.

Comment: This answer showed me that the results for /(train|trainer)/ is different from /(trainer|train)/. So it's a good idea to sort a list of words by length before transforming it into a group. It solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
perl -Mstrict -Mre=/xp -MData::Dumper -wE'
  {package Data::Dumper;our($Indent,$Sortkeys,$Terse,$Useqq)=(1)x4}
  sub _dump { Dumper(shift) =~ s{(\[.*?\])}{$1=~s/\s+/ /gr}srge }
  my ($count, %RS);
  my $s= "aaaabbaaaaabbab";
  $s =~ m{ \G a+b? (?{ $RS{ $+[0] - $-[0] } //= [ ${^MATCH}, $-[0] ]; $count++ }) (*FAIL) };
  say sprintf "RS: %s", _dump(\%RS);
  say sprintf "count: %s", $count;
'
RS: {
  "1" => [ "a", 0 ],
  "2" => [ "aa", 0 ],
  "3" => [ "aaa", 0 ],
  "4" => [ "aaaa", 0 ],
  "5" => [ "aaaab", 0 ]
}

count: 5
```

Comment: It would help if you would write some text around this. Code-only answers are usually not very well received here, especially if the code looks like a [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) submission.

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).