# Difference between the behaviour of awk and perl in regex alternation

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, grep

Look into this:

```
$ echo sixty | awk '{ sub(/six|sixty/, "X"); print }'
X
$ echo sixty | perl -pe 's/six|sixty/X/'
Xty
```

`perl` stops at the first match and `awk` continues to search for a "better" match. `sed` and `grep` behave same as `awk`. Why does the behaviour of `awk/sed/grep` and `perl` differ in regular expression alternation, and is this difference documented anywhere?

Comment: They have two totally different regex machines built in. `regex` is not one language. It has a big number of dialects.

Comment: In perl you can match the longest alternative by reordering the alternatives such that the longest comes first: `echo sixty | perl -pe 's/sixty|six/X/'`, see [Perl 5 - longest token matching in regexp (using alternation)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15035862/2173773) for more information

Comment: See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) and [my tutorial](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnuawk/regular-expressions.html#longest-match-wins)